# Want \addtocontents{toc} without \addtocontents{ptc}

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

When using partial tables of contents `ptc` [from the `titletoc` package],
how do I add to the global table of contents
without also adding to the partial table of contents?

`\addcontentsline{toc}{<sectionType>}{<code>}` adds to `ptc` and `toc`.
`\addcontentsline{ptc}{<sectionType>}{<code>}` adds to `ptc`

How do I add to `toc` only?

**Also**:

I believe this also applies with
`\addtotableofcontents{toc}{<code>}`
`\addtotableofcontents{ptc}{<code>}`

Comment: Please provide the code of a *complete*, small document that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick, change locally tocdepth

```
\addtocontents{ptc}{\begingroup\string\makeatletter\string\c@tocdepth -3\relax}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foo}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\endgroup}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{1}{\hrule}

\addtocontents{ptc}{\begingroup\string\makeatletter\string\c@tocdepth -3\relax}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foo}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\endgroup}

\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any difference between the two TOCs.

Comment: @murray the first one  start with **Foo** (section)

Comment: OK, but not a substantial difference such as I expected to see.

Comment: @murray I am sorry, This is the question: add something (Foo) only to  the global toc and not to the partial one.